# dictionary interface for large data sets

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset, large-files

I have a set of key/values (all text) that is too large to load in memory at once. I would like to interact with this data via a Python dictionary-like interface.

Does such a module already exist?

Reading key values should be efficient and values compressed on disk to save space.

Edit:

- Ideally cross platform, but only using Linux for now
- Needs to be thread safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up creating [my own solution](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/source/browse/pdict.py) based on [this existing module](http://code.google.com/p/persistentdict/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module. It provides dictionaries with various backing database systems include BerkleyDB and dbm.

Comment: unfortunately "does not support concurrent read/write access"

Answer (score 1):

Try [bsddb(Python bindings for Berkley db)](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a *nix platform, you are just BEGGING for tokyo-cabinet... It has a native set of ruby bindings... You can more information at 1978th.net...

Comment: Wow, I'm miss reading posts left right and center today... My bad